# Spark conversion from string to TimestampType

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I see something I dont understand when I convert TimeStamp value from string into TimeStamp type in spark.
Spark version I use is 2.11

Here is the code.

```
val t = sc.parallelize(Array("2018-02-16T12:46:29.336+00:00")).toDF("t")
t.select(t.col("t").cast(TimestampType).as("t")).show(false)
```

and the result is.

```
+-----------------------+
|t                      |
+-----------------------+
|2018-02-16 13:46:29.336|
```

What confuses me is the hour changes from 12 to 13 even when the timezone is +00:00.

And when I change the timezone to +01:00 like below

```
val t = sc.parallelize(Array("2018-02-16T12:46:29.336+01:00")).toDF("t")
t.select(t.col("t").cast(TimestampType).as("t")).show(false)
```

result is now. There is no change in hour value.
t: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [t: string]

```
+-----------------------+
|t                      |
+-----------------------+
|2018-02-16 12:46:29.336|
+-----------------------+
```

I run spark locally on my laptop which is in timezone UTC+1. Does cast function converts the timezone automatically based on machine timezone? If yes how to avoid this?

Can some one help me here?